# How can I send multiple async requests in Flutter that is not just concurrent but parallel?

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, parallel-processing, just-audio

I am calling a TTS API for multiple lines of texts. Ideally I would like to have them executed in parallel, meaning that one request would not wait for the other to finish before starting, hence speeding up total runtime of the API calls.

Here is an excerpt from my code:

```
    await Future.forEach(rounds, (round) async {
      await _fetchAudioForText(
          round, voiceA );
      totalBytes += round.audio?.lengthInBytes ?? 0;
    });
```

...

```
  Future<bool> _fetchAudioForText(Round round, Voice voice) async {
    round.audio =
        await ttsUtils.getAudioByteStream(round.text, voice);
    return true;
  }
```

getAudioByteStream is essentially calling the TTS API using a HTTP request and has a return type of a byte stream (Uint8List).

The problem is, that it's not actually doing it in parallel. What am I missing here?

Comment: Use `Future.wait` to get concurrency (and possibly parallelism, depending on the implementation of the underlying asynchronous operations).  Your current code executes *serially* and not concurrently.

Answer (score -1):

remove await in forEach

```
await Future.forEach(rounds, (round) async {
  _fetchAudioForText(
    round, voiceA );
  totalBytes += round.audio?.lengthInBytes ?? 0;
});
```

Comment: This will result in `totalBytes` not being computed correctly, and it will prevent callers from determining when the entire operation is complete.